# Editing every file in a directory after opening it bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Looking around I didn't see exactly what I was looking for. Some similar stuff, but for some reason what I tried so far hasn't worked.

My main goals:

1. run script in my current directory
2. open the picture to see what it is
3. rename the picture i just viewed
4. repeat the process without running the script again

---

These were the sources I attempted to follow:

[Bash Shell Loop Over Set of Files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)

[Bash loop through directory and rename every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131146/bash-loop-through-directory-and-rename-every-file)

[How to do something to every file in a directory using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310422/how-to-do-something-to-every-file-in-a-directory-using-bash)

==================================================================================

```
echo "Rename pictures. Path"
read path
for f in $path
do  
    eog $path
    echo "new name"
    read newname
    mv $path $newname
    cat $f
done
```

Comment: did you try adding `&&` after the `eog` line? `eog $path &&`

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes, what benefit does that provide? If you wanted to avoid running the rest of that loop iteration for a file where `eog` fails, then `eog "$path" || continue` would do a better job of it (skipping not just the `echo`, but also the `read`, `mv` and `cat`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
for f in $*; do
    eog $f
    echo "new name:"
    read newname
    mv $f $newname
done
```

If you name the script, say, `rename.sh`, you can call

```
./rename.sh *gif
```

to review all files with extention 'gif'.

Comment: `for f in $*; do` is extremely buggy -- if you ran `yourscript "argument one" "argument two"`, it would treat that as `"argument" "one" "argument" "two"`, splitting on whitespace and losing the boundaries implied by the original quoting. Use `for f in "$@"; do` instead, or just `for f; do`.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the script an argument rather than trying to make it interactive. You also have numerous quoting problems. Try something like this instead (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

moveFile() {
    local newName=
    until [[ $newName ]]; do
        printf '%s ' 'new name:'
        read -er newName # -e implies Bash with readline
        echo
    done
    mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}/${newName}"
}

if [[ ! -d $1 ]]; then
    echo 'Must specify a path' >&2
    exit 1
fi

for f in "$1"/*; do
    eog "$f"
    moveFile "$f"
done
```

Comment: when you call a function as you have here my system seems to ignore it (simple cut and paste) anything i have to make sure i do to make the function moveFile() recognized

Comment: @user1770303 I don't believe so. There are a few bashisms in use here so firstly make sure you're actually using bash (with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang). This script assumes you're passing the directory as an arg of course. Use `set -x` or run as `bash -x scriptname` to debug. You should see the function call and its argument in the output. **edit** also see I made a typo... copy/paste again :)

Answer (score -2):

Using `find` command allows you to search for image files in the specified directory recursively.

```
echo -n "Rename pictures. Input image directory: "
read path

for f in `find $path -type f`
do
    eog $f
    echo -n "Enter new name: "
    read newname
    mv $f $newname
    echo "Renamed $f to $newname."
done
```

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- iterating on output from `for` this way is quite buggy, failing on filenames with spaces or whose names can be interpreted as globs. Moreover, the variable expansions need to be quoted (`"$f", `"$newname"`, etc) to be correct; see http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Also, `echo -n` is best avoided; see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section, advising `printf` instead.